# createDrawerNavigation() has been moved to react-navigation-drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

[createDrawerNavigation() has been moved to react-navigation-drawer. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator.html for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoadY.jpg)

Comment: Uhh, is this a question or a statement?

Answer (score 10):

It seems like you're trying to import `createDrawerNavigator()` from the `react-navigation` library. However, this function has since moved to `react-navigation-drawer`. The error already tells you exactly what's happening. If you take a look at [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html) this error links you, you'll find what to import:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

Comment: You will need to install it doing `npm i react-navigation-drawer`, as it's not a package that's automatically downloaded when installing react-navigation

Comment: can you check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605603/element-type-is-invalid-when-use-react-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

For starters>

For App.js imports in project or src, remove {createDrawerNavigator} from import from "react-navigation" to 'react-navigation-drawer'

ex:
From => import {**createDrawerNavigator,** createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";

Remove => import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";

To => import {**createDrawerNavigator**} from 'react-navigation-drawer';